# Por que não printa a variavel contato[0]->a?

Tags: c, ponteiro, struct

Ponteiros ainda me confunde principalmente em situações do tipo. A ideia é simples. Estou tentando criar um vetor de ponteiros do tipo `struct`. Porém devo estar utilizando alguma ideia errada de ponteiros pois o programa não está exibindo o que peço.
Queria saber o que pode estar errado. Se eu sanar essa dúvida já vai me ajudar muito. Um muito obrigado a quem quiser e puder me auxiliar.

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct agenda_x
{
    char nome[50];
    char tel[10];
    int a;
};

struct agenda_x *contato[2];

int main()
{
    contato[0]->a=4;
    printf("%i",contato[0]->a);
}
```

Comment: Se te confundem, o que acha da ideia de fazer algo mais simples até pegar o jeito e depois disso partir para algo mais sofisticado?

Comment: É porque é trabalho então não tem jeito kskskkssk Mas acho que entendi o que ocorreu

Answer (score 0):

Você ta declarando um ponteiro pra vetores de 2 posições e não tá alocando... Como é uma variável global, tá sendo inicializado pra NULL, testa o seguinte:

```
if(contato[0] == NULL)
    printf("valor nao inicializado");
```

E observe que você ta tentando referenciar um ponteiro nulo.

Pra corrigir tenho as seguintes sugestões:

1 - Ou você adiciona a seguinte linha antes de atribuir o valor 4:

```
contato[0] = (struct agenda_x*) malloc(sizeof (struct agenda_x));
```

2 - ou pode alterar o código todo para o seguinte:

```
struct agenda_x contato[2];

int main()
{
   contato[0].a=4;
   printf("%i",contato[0].a);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que você esteja com alguma dificuldade ao compreender a inicialização do ponteiro para a struct. Isso é normal, vamos lá:
Ao fazer

```
struct agenda_x *contato[2]
```

Você está criando um array de ponteiros que apontará para agenda_x, e não um array com 2 espaços do tipo struct agenda_x.
Acredito que você queira o espaço para salvar 2 contatos, então há duas opções:

```
struct agenda_x *contato;
contato = (struct agenda_x *) malloc(2*sizeof(struct agenda_x);
```

Agora, alocamos 2 espaços para utilizar como contato. Podemos usar contato[0] e contato[1] sem termos problemas de memória.
Você ainda pode fazer:

```
struct agenda_x contato[2];
```

Se você tratar essa struct como um ponteiro, como no primeiro caso, em que se utiliza malloc, você utilizará a notação contato->a para acessar o primeiro elemento (se quiser acessar outro, basta incrementar o contato *contato++, caso contrário, utilizará contato[0].a e contato[1].a para acessar os elementos.
Espero ter ajudado.

Obs: o malloc deverá ser feito dentro de uma função, mas a variável pode ser declarada como global sem problemas.